# referencing class variable to a local variable

Tags: java

why do some people make a new reference in method to a field variable?

```
public class Foo {
    int mFoo[] = {1, 2, 3};

    void method() {
        int foo[] = mFoo; // WHY not just use mFoo?

        print(foo[0]); // WHY not just use mFoo?
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe they think its marginally faster (which it could be). Or maybe to avoid threading issues.

Comment: @scrappedcola if I change 'foo[0]=5' the same will also reflect to mFoo.

Comment: @Thilo Threading issues?  Can you elaborate how that helps?

Comment: @EricB. see the accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be a good idea if for example, at another place of your code, you change the value of mFoo. Especially in a multithreaded context, you would want to ensure you're still working on the right data.

Comment: if I would change 'foo[0]=5' it will also reflect on mFoo. 
So could you elaborate why this would be different in multithreaded context?

Comment: Imagine you are in a multithreaded app. In one of your thread, you begin to iterate on your table. In another thread, you execute `mFoo=anotherTable;` What happens next in your iterating thread?

Answer (score 3):

It used to be the case (and still is with Java ME AFAIK) that loading a field into a local variable and using it multiple times was faster than access a field multiple times.

However, today using a local variable this way can confuse the JIT compiler and using a local variable this way can be slower.

Comment: Really?  I can't imagine this slowing things down.  (I have seen recent benchmarks demonstrating speedups with this technique even on Java 7 -server, but only tiny ones in extremely performance-critical code.)

Comment: This was a claim by one of the JVM developers less than a month ago. I imagine it depends on the situation. I haven't seen it myself. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goal. If you want to modify whatever Object was passed in as a parameter you would not make a new instance of the type of the referenced Object.

Otherwise you would make a new instance which would you could modify freely without worrying about modifications to the passed in Object. This is commonly used in multi-threaded applications.

Comment: Making new instances is not mentioned in the question, though.

Answer (score 2):

There's an accepted answer already, but the use makes more sense in this context:

```
private Class<?> clazz = ...;

public void foo() {
    Class<?> current = clazz;
    while (current != Object.class) {
        // do some stuff.
        current = current.superclass();
    }
}
```

In this example you are constantly re-assigning "current" to a new value.  Imagine the side effect without the variable, and if you kept doing:

```
clazz = clazz.superclass();
```

You'd be changing the field in the object itself, not locally to your method, so repeated calls to "foo" would not exhibit the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: the accepted answer was the first one that clarified me the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It just doesn't make sense if you use just like this:

```
int[] local = somethingElse;
... // changes to local will reflect on somethingElse
```

It would make sense if a real copy would be done like:

```
int[] local = Arrays.copyOf(somethingElse,somethingElse.lenght())
... // changes to local will not reflect on somethingElse
```

The copy can prevent changing the elements that you will need on your method invoking other methods or by other Threads interference. In case that you have for example a method that changes this elements invoked at the same time you are using them. So, you can make a copy and work with them without being concern about the modification applied to it.

A test can be done with the following code:

```
int[] test = new int[] {1,2,3};
int[] test2 = Arrays.copyOf(test,test.length);
test2[0] = 9;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of primitive types like **int** you're coping the values, not pointer, so your original array is still untouched after invoking method "print". It doesnt hold though for arrays

Comment: if we have int arrays then we are also just pointing and not copying.
this would be copying:
    int i=5;
     int j=i;